# How can I tell which page serves me?

Tags: php, javascript, browser, dns

I am on a website. the URL reads something like `https://somesite.com/serve`

I need to tell the name of the page that is serving me.

Like `index.html`, `index.htm`, etc...

Comment: Like "page.php"? Like "site.jsp"? Like "website.wsgi"?

Comment: In PHP or JavaScript? You tagged both.

Comment: Try and trigger a server error like with a malformed HTTP/1.0 request perhaps it will print the server version or use a tool like this net-square.com/httprint/, If the server is running apache then you can almost guarantee its a php driven site with mod_rewrite, also by looking at the source of a script you can pick out the specific script from similarity's, like with wp. Tho like with most things its almost impossible to be sure unless the info is made public

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fundamentally impossible for you find that out.

Comment: What about using a bookmarklet? Javascript can return the URL

Comment: @Paul: There's still no reliable way to map a URL to a file.

Comment: Ok, how is this done then ? How can my browser possibly not know the page name it is accessing? is that not fundamental HTTP ?

Comment: HTTP has **nothing** to do with what file the data is coming from.

Comment: @Ted: HTTP has nothing to do with files.

Comment: Pinterest does it all day long ;)

Comment: I thought the file was the resource requested by regular GET. Are you saying that through .htaccess you can change the way the URL looks to the user?

Comment: HTTP deals with **URLs**. What backing the URL has is none of HTTP's business.

Comment: So that leaves me kind of clueless about that.

Comment: @Ted: Yes you can totally rewrite a url to something completely different

Comment: Use .htaccess RewriteRule to put regex-matching filenames in a header. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309102/setting-a-filename-inside-the-header-with-htaccess/9319408#9319408

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the file that is being served. Well probably you are facing url rewrite  with htaccess or other techniques. To tell which file it is probably is impossible if only you manage to get framework (if it is framework) in which the page is made. Then you can read in documentation which is the file to which the requests are aimed. Most frameworks will have one or several of these files. For example codeignighter will have only index.php, while symfony 2 will have app.php and app_dev.php (and others if you want different environments). But normaly you cant know which file serves your request if url rewrite is made.

---

As mentioned @Dale you cant also beleave what urls say. Because you cant stick some extension at the end for it to look as file. Sometimes you can notice .php or more often .html / .htm at the end.

Comment: And it may not even be using PHP in the first place.

Comment: But could use the file extension .php even if it isn't!

Comment: Yes. That is due to HTTP. Response Headers wont contain this inteligence. And all softwares using this protocol will lack this information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean. But I'm certain you can find it with $_SERVER (Documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php))

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you just trying to find out the page name then you can do this:

```
<?php
$currentFile = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$parts = explode('/', $currentFile);
echo $parts[count($parts) - 1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

probably then you have a [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) with [rewrite rules](http://mirificampress.com/permalink/beyond_redirect_using_rewriterules_in_htaccess) which looks something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Else you probably would have query string instead which probably looked something like:

```
index.php?c=products&m=view&id=345
```

Comment: What has the CodeIgniter user guide htaccess file got to do with this question? :-)

Comment: That's not what the question is though.

Comment: The rewrite rule would probably tell you more. But you are right. It is not the best answer...

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming server supports .htaccess, mod_rewrite, mod_headers)

*Temporarily* use .htaccess RewriteRule to reveal all or matching filenames in a header.

Example tags all php file headers with filename:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        RewriteRule .*\.php$ - [E=FILENAME:$0]
        <FilesMatch ".php$">
           Header set MY-COOL-FILENAME "filename=%{FILENAME}e"
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Links

[Setting a filename inside the header with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309102/setting-a-filename-inside-the-header-with-htaccess/9319408#9319408)

[View HTTP headers in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome)