# Add path name to downloading file name

Tags: .htaccess, filenames, content-disposition

I want people to be able to download several files that sum up lessons I am teaching. Files are pdf organized in folders like this:

```
.htaccess
01-science/
   lesson-1/
      notes.pdf
      slides.pdf
   lesson-2/
      notes.pdf
      slides.pdf
…
```

The `.htaccess` file already forces files to be downloaded with these commands:

```
<Files *.pdf>
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

I am giving the direct URL to reach the files, for instance `https://lessons.domain.my/01-science/lesson-1/notes.pdf`. But, to avoid confusion, at downloading, I'd like filenames to be prefixed with folder names to give this:

```
01-science-lesson-1-notes.pdf
01-science-lesson-1-slides.pdf
```

Maybe a regex in the  could do this, but I can't get which one… Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309102/setting-a-filename-inside-the-header-with-htaccess#9319408), I have found the proper .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.pdf$ - [E=FILENAME:$0]
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=%{FILENAME}e"
</FilesMatch>
```

Thus the URL `https://lessons.domain.my/01-science/lesson-1/notes.pdf` downloads the file `notes.pdf` under the name `01-science_lesson-1_notes.pdf` which fits perfectly.

As I do not know the `.htaccess` syntax very well, this remains opened to any better suggestion or comment…

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your main directory `,htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.pdf$  /$1-$2-$3.pdf [L,NE,R=302]
```

If everything goes Ok , change `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work, since I want to keep the folders structures on the server and only have the file renamed at downloading…